# How Can I download this file: values.xml

Tags: java

the file in this directory:
C:\Users\user.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\3a4beccd096fd786f5bb4c1e46d3cf34\material-1.8.0\res\values

I made some change to this file by mistake so I need to download the original one, can you tell me how can download it?
thank you

I made search for that but could not find it.

Comment: Please explain and show the details of your question and your problem. If you haven't yet gone through the [ask], how would be a great time to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gradle](https://gradle.org/) is a build tool. If you clear the cache, Gradle should be able to rebuild it from scratch the next time you build your project. One way to clear the cache is to delete everything under `C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches`.